# Last stone in hand landing in Mancala

Tags: mancala

When your last stone in your hand lands in your store (Mancala), is it  optional or required to take an extra turn?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding something but how can you take another turn if you have no stones left?

Comment: Last stone in hand, I presume.  Since this is the trigger for getting an extra turn.

Answer (score 1):

You **Must** take another turn.

> When the last seed in your hand lands in your store, take another turn.

[Source: mancala_rules](https://harriscenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/mancala_rules.pdf)